# Query errors in DOMXPath

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

I'm trying to parse a xml file using DOMXPath class in PHP but I get some errors when I do queries. My XML have something like this

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news><new><title><!CDATA[bla bla bla]]></title><content><!CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></content></new></news>
```

**DOMXPath**

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load( $filename );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $xml );

$news = $xpath->query('//news');
```

The $news length is always 0, and news tag exists in xml file.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,

Ismael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

I have modified some of your code :

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $doc->Load('book.xml');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    // We starts from the root element
    $query = '//news';

    $news = $xpath->query($query);
    print_r($news); 

?>
```

I am getting length value `1`

**book.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news><new><title>adsds</title><content>asdsa</content></new></news>
```

Comment: You did the same misstake as me... You removed the CDATA tag which is why he had errors.

Comment: @Shirraz : but the `object value omitted` error i am getting because of the `CDATA` tag.

Comment: Yeah, cause his CDATA is malformed... that's why I "simplified" his the same way you did, then things simply worked as intended... The CDATA tag is the problem here, not the query (besides querying "all the root tag")...

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're querying the root tag ("news"), which is somewhat useless since there's only one root tag per XML file. Actually, you query is the same as `query('/news')`, which lengths will always be "1".

For your problem, note that your CDATA is malformed. It's `<![CDATA[blah blah blah]]>`, not `<!CDATA[bla bla bla]]` (missing bracket before `CDATA`).

This works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news>
  <new><title><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></title><content><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></content></new>
  <new><title><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></title><content><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></content></new>
  <new><title><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></title><content><![CDATA[<p>bla bla bla</p>]]></content></new>
</news>
```

PHP script

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('./test.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $xml );

$news = $xpath->query('//new');

var_dump($news->length);
```

Perfectly returns "3".

Comment: Inside `<news>` I have some `<new>` tags, if I do `query('//new')` also I get length = 0.

Comment: updated my answer, at first I replaced your CDATAs with simple strings... Bad idea, I missed your malformed tag ;)

Here is why it worked for me at first ;)